# How to retain information queried from database

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am in the process of rewriting some old software. This process has been done before using a indexed collection to store the information that was queried from the database. Then later referenced by way of the indexed value. That's great and all, but the larger portion of this software that needs to be redone queries information from a table that uses two fields as a primary key.

Is there away for a collection to use two fields as an index?

Is there a work around if not?

Is there a better way to achieve the desired results than using a collection?

Thanks!

Comment: what is wrong with using DataSet and/or DataTable?  Its pretty much what they are intended for.

Comment: There is also the `Entity Framework`

Comment: The collection mentioned was done before me. I, not having any formal education with vb.net, have learned this process by studying the aforementioned code. I don't know how to use DataSet, DataTable, or Entity Framework. But I will most definitely research these solutions.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you will have to override the GetHashCode method of your class to something like this:

```
Public Overloads Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
    return Key1.ToString.GetHashCode() Xor Key2.ToString.GetHashCode()
End Function
```

The above code assumes Key1 and Key2 are your properties you want to makeup your uniqueness.